# Flashback - Check if data ever existed in table in particular duration - Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, flashback

Is there a way to check if data ever exists in a table before in Oracle?

Using flashback option, 
we can check for data like `as of timestamp sysdate - x` (where x is time we'd like to see data in past)

But I'd like to know is there any function or utility which Oracle provides so we can know if one particular data ever existed in a table in last 1 week or something.

Comment: It really depends on how big your flashback area is set-up and how "busy" your oracle db is.

Comment: @TedatORCL.Pro- how can I know these parameters?

Comment: The following statement changes the flashback time from the default of one day to two days:

SQL> alter system set db_flashback_retention_target = 2880;

Comment: Don't use the `mysql` tag if you're not asking about MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the Flash Recovery Area (FRA) is full and the Oracle DBA wants to know what is it use, size and the list of occupants (archives, RMAN backups pieces or image copies, flashback logs).

Compatibility: Oracle 12c, 11g, 10g

```
-- Utilisation (MB) du FRA
set lines 100
col name format a60

select
   name,
  floor(space_limit / 1024 / 1024) "Size MB",
  ceil(space_used / 1024 / 1024) "Used MB"
from v$recovery_file_dest;

-- FRA Occupants
SELECT * FROM V$FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA_USAGE;

-- Location and size of the FRA
show parameter db_recovery_file_dest

-- Size, used, Reclaimable 
SELECT
  ROUND((A.SPACE_LIMIT / 1024 / 1024 / 1024), 2) AS FLASH_IN_GB, 
  ROUND((A.SPACE_USED / 1024 / 1024 / 1024), 2) AS FLASH_USED_IN_GB, 
  ROUND((A.SPACE_RECLAIMABLE / 1024 / 1024 / 1024), 2) AS FLASH_RECLAIMABLE_GB,
  SUM(B.PERCENT_SPACE_USED)  AS PERCENT_OF_SPACE_USED
FROM
  V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST A,
  V$FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA_USAGE B
GROUP BY
  SPACE_LIMIT, 
  SPACE_USED , 
  SPACE_RECLAIMABLE ;

-- After that you can resize the FRA with:
-- ALTER SYSTEM SET db_recovery_file_dest_size=xxG;

-- Or change the FRA to a new location (new archives will be created to this new location):
-- ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST='/u....';
```

The following statement changes the flashback time from the default of one day to two days:

SQL> alter system set db_flashback_retention_target = 2880;

Comment: great..how can I reach to what I'm looking for like 'if particular data ever happened to exist in a table in last few days (lets say 7)'

Comment: Set the retention to 7+ days and give enough storage to FRA, the rest is Oracle Magic ;)